# Is it possible to estimate the number of people in a room from a limited number of simultaneously recorded audio samples?

Tags: specific-reference, acoustics, signal-processing

*Note: I struggled to decide the appropriate site for this question, between https://physics.stackexchange.com/, https://video.stackexchange.com/, https://math.stackexchange.com/, and even https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/. However, I felt that the Audio-Video Production and Linguistics communities might not provide the mathematically inspired answer I'm looking for, and the Mathematics community might dismiss the question as being ill-defined—I thought the Physics community might come up with important points and counterpoints to practical applications, in addition to having mathematical background.*

---

**Is it possible to estimate the number of people in a room from a limited number of simultaneously recorded audio samples?**

I'm searching on Google Scholar by combinations of keywords like [recording](/questions/tagged/recording), [audio](/questions/tagged/audio), [extrapolate](/questions/tagged/extrapolate), [crowd](/questions/tagged/crowd), [number](/questions/tagged/number), [voices](/questions/tagged/voices), etc. and not coming up with any papers related to my question. It's made me wonder whether there's some mathematical or physical impasse that makes the task *necessarily* impossible. If so, what are the principles that exclude this possibility? If not obviously impossible, could someone perhaps point me to some research regarding this particular problem?

To be more specific, though I'm sure it's naive, my idea was to take two stereo recordings from different locations in a crowded room, and to analyze certain linguistic features like the rate of hisses (or other utterances and features of a language that are easy to isolate), to derive a statistically useful range estimating the number of persons in the crowd. (Of course, such a system would have to be calibrated to a uniform language or dialect.)

I'm aware of various *difficulties*, both technical (such as how to synchronize the recordings, how to achieve high sensitivity with low noise, etc.) and fundamental (such as how to distinguish between one person speaking profusely and others barely speaking), but I'm more trying to find out if one or more principles of mathematics or physics regarding an audio signal itself, in its "flattened" form, might preemptively shut down this idea. I'm afraid I don't know enough physics myself to explore the problem :-(

Thank you in advance for any insights or references.

Comment: It occurred to me just now that electrical engineering might be a candidate site for this question as well. So if anyone would argue in _favor_ of EE as being more appropriate for this question than this site, then please upvote this comment and I will move the question accordingly.

Comment: A physicist is going to have a hard time working with the frequency of different sounds that people tend to make during speech, but I'll try to pose a physicist's version of the problem: Suppose there are several microphones situated in a room, and there are several sound sources (possibly moving) in the room. Given the synchronized data from the microphones, is it possible to estimate the number of sources? I think the answer should be yes. I think the main thing to think about is that the intensity from farther sources will be less. There may be information to be gained from time of travel.

Comment: This is def a [dsp.se] question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution you seek is partially given by *Independent Component Analysis* (ICA) (see this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_component_analysis) article, this [tutorial](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.2986.pdf), this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-ica-independent-component-analysis-b2c3c4720cd9) and this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/independent-component-analysis) for more information). ICA was developed to solve problems in the field of *Blind Source Separation* (BSS).

To briefly discuss what ICA is about, you can think of it as the *Principal Component Analysis* (PCA). In the latter, some signals which are mixed linearly, are separated into the components that provide the most information (have the largest variance). In PCA the assumptions are that the signals have a Gaussian *Probability Density Function* (PDF) and the resulting components are orthogonal. On the contrary, in ICA, it is a prerequisite for the signals to **not** be Gaussian, as higher moments are used, which for Gaussian PDFs are zero. Furthermore, in ICA, the resulting components are not necessarily orthogonal and, in most cases, they are not. The components that the mixtures are decomposed to are independent, hence the term in the name of the method.

To the best of my (limited) knowledge, the number of components the decomposition/analysis can provide is equal to the number of measured signals you have. That is, you can get as many independent components as the microphones (or whatever sensors/measurement apparatus) you use. This is a considerable limitation in many applications if a large number of signals have to be separated. Finally, it is extremely beneficial for the *Signal-to-Noise Ratio* (SNR) between the signals to be separated to be as high as possible. In practice, this means that in each of your signals/recordings, a single source should be dominant. For low SNRs the algorithm will still separate the signals but the accuracy will be compromised.

To conclude, you can find a rather efficient algorithmic implementation termed FastICA in C++, Python, R and MATLAB [here](http://research.ics.aalto.fi/ica/fastica/) from the researchers that introduced the method in Aalto University.